# "NONCOMMUTATIVE Algebra with a view towards Algebraic Geometry"?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request, noncommutative-algebra, reference-works

Is there a noncommutative algebra book that is similar to Eisenbud's "Commutative Algebra with a view towards Algebraic Geometry" in the sense that fundamental and geometrically motivated notions are covered in a systematic manner ? I was trying to look one online but found myself not knowing where to even start.

Thanks!

Comment: Noncommutative objects are somewhat rare in algebraic geometry - the only ones that come to my mind immediately are differential operators and maybe quantum groups. What sort of "fundamental and geometrically motivated notions" are you looking for?

Comment: I fear that books on non-commutative algebra/geometry will presuppose knowing, or at least build on, the commutative case. Maybe try https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noncommutative_algebraic_geometry#References for inspiration. If you are happy venturing outside pure algebra you can look up D-modules and rings of differential operators, where the fundamental rings in question are non-commutative, and the whole area is highly geometrically motivated (but you will have to deal with at least some analysis, and in worst case a lot of it).

Comment: @KReiser I'm interested in topics that are of "structural" importance, such as flatness, smoothness, etc. in commutative algebra. I know that there are formulations of noncommutative algebraic geometry that are founded on monoidal categories of quasi-coherent modules over "spaces", but again, I don't think I know how to navigate the literature yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure you will find a single textbook with all informations. As suggested in comment, one answer could be "look up any book on $D$-modules" (for example these [lectures](http://math.uchicago.edu/%7Edrinfeld/langlands/Bernstein/Bernstein-dmod.ps) by Bernstein are very good).

Here are some other pointers that could be useful :

These [lectures](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0506603) by Ginzburg on non-commutative geometry, that contains a lot of important constructions. I really learned a lot just by reading the first chapters.

These [lectures](http://people.math.harvard.edu/%7Egaitsgde/267y/catO.pdf) by Gaitsgory on geometric representation theory. It includes the study of category $\mathcal O$ for complex semisimple Lie algebras $\mathfrak g$, and the study of $\mathscr D$-modules, an important example of non-commutative algebras appearing in algebraic geometry.

I also think that books on Hochschild cohomology are relevant : these [lectures](https://pbelmans.ncag.info/assets/hh-2018-notes.pdf) by Pieter Belmans are geometry-oriented, and this [book](https://bookstore.ams.org/gsm-204) by Sarah Witherspoon is more algebraic but still could be a good reference.

Comment: I think it's worth remarking that, while there are various flavours of noncommutative geometry, there is no obvious noncommutative analogue to algebraic geometry, in the sense that there's no 'affine schemes' corresponding to noncommutative rings in all ways you may hope.

Comment: See, for instance, this old answer by Emerton on MathOverflow, which I've found very inspiring: https://mathoverflow.net/a/15196/172450

Comment: @JeroenvanderMeer : indeed, very inspiring ! I think the general philosophy of non-commutative algebraic geometry is still clear, and it has already produced many interesting results (for example localisation of $\mathfrak g$-module on the quantum flag variety, by the work of Backelin-Kremnitzer ). But I agree with you that there is no "obvious" analogue, rather a guiding philosophy to take space of functions (or category of sheaves) as primary object.

Comment: @JeroenvanderMeer Thanks for pointing out the answer by Emerton (along with that whole MO thread)!

Comment: @NicolasHemelsoet Thanks for your list of references. The lectures by Ginzburg in particular really interest me.